# Eclipse lost its ability to run/debug java applications

Tags: java, eclipse

When I am trying to run an app nothing happens (console remains empty).

[image]

I suspect workspace corruption. How to fix?

**UPDATE**

Sorry guys, my actual question was this. When I tried to create SSCCE, I made another mistake (wrong `main` signature) and thought it was due to the same problem.

**MY FAULT**

Sorry forgot about my custom perspective. When debug panel is not visible, breakpoints are also don't. It was waiting on breakpoint.

Comment: is the project getting built successfully?

Comment: i suspect user error :)

Answer (score 3):

Your method called `main` misses the arguments variable to be **the** `main` that Java Interpreter invokes when Java application is starts.

This is how `main` should look like:

```
public static void main(String ... args) {
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Comment: incorrect there is another option that works, return type of int

Comment: No the return type must be `void`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct implementations of a runnable main are as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {}   
public static void main(String... args) {} 
public static int main(String[] args) {}  
public static int main(String... args) {}
```

What you have declared above is a function that happens to be called main.

**EDIT**

Since you have changed the question:

Make sure you have the correct console selected, there is a drop down and I suspect you have the wrong one open.  Additionally make sure your color scheme isn't white text + white background.

Comment: Drop down is dimmed as you see on screenshot

Comment: @Dims bad monitor on my end

Comment: So, just nothing happens after run. No text on console, no breakpoint hit.

Comment: @Dims did you run in debug mode?  The icon with the little green bug on it.